# Append date and time to an environment variable in linux makefile

Tags: makefile, environment-variables

In my Makefile I want to create an environment variable using the current date and time.  Pseudo code:

```
LOG_FILE := $LOG_PATH + $SYSTEM_DATE + $SYSTEM_TIME
```

Any help appreciated - thanks.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

you can use this:

```
LOGFILE=$(LOGPATH) `date +'%y.%m.%d %H:%M:%S'`
```

NOTE (from comments):

it will cause LOGFILE to be evaluated every time while used.
to avoid that:

```
LOGFILE=$(LOGPATH)$(shell date)
```

Comment: Won't this cause LOGFILE to be evaulated everytime it is used.  

For example:

LOGFILE=logs/`date +'%y.%m.%d-%H:%M:%S'`

echo_logs:
     echo $(LOGFILE)
     sleep 5s
     echo $($LOGFILE)

will print:

echo logs/`date +'%y.%m.%d-%H:%M:%S'`
logs/10.01.28-14:21:08
sleep 5s
echo logs/`date +'%y.%m.%d-%H:%M:%S'`
logs/10.01.28-14:21:13

Comment: @Aaron: You are right; to avoid this one can use gnu make `shell` function instead of backticks: `LOGFILE=$(LOGPATH)$(shell date)`

Comment: Agreed, and for completeness: LOGFILE=$(LOGPATH)$(shell date +'%Y.%m.%d-%H:%M:%S'). Also works on Solaris.

Comment: The value of `LOGFILE` wont stay same across multiple target.  Specially if one has dependency to other.

Comment: Create make file `echo -e 'TM=$(shell date +%s.%N)\n\na:\n\techo $(TM)\n\tsleep 2\nb: a\n\techo $(TM)\n' > Makefile`. Then call the dependent target. `make b`. You'll see times are different.

Answer (score 48):

You need to use the $(shell operation) command in make.  If you use `operation`, then the shell command will get evaluated every time. If you are writing to a log file, you don't want the log file name to change every time you access it in a single make command.

```
LOGPATH = logs
LOGFILE = $(LOGPATH)/$(shell date --iso=seconds)

test_logfile:
    echo $(LOGFILE)
    sleep 2s
    echo $(LOGFILE)
```

This will output:

```
echo logs/2010-01-28T14:29:14-0800
logs/2010-01-28T14:29:14-0800
sleep 2s
echo logs/2010-01-28T14:29:14-0800
logs/2010-01-28T14:29:14-0800
```

Comment: But this doesn't stay same on different target.

Comment: @ShipluMokaddim Use `:=` to keep the same for the entire Makefile.