# Auto versioning on Blazor Wasm

Tags: c#, blazor, versioning, visual-studio-2022, webassembly

I'm currently working on a **Blazor WASM** app and I'd like to set a custom version (formatted like **`YEAR.MONTH.DAY.REVISION`**) to all my built assemblies. 
 My goal is to use a makefile that does some stuff and compile the solution while setting the assemblies version.

I've already tried an extension for **Visual Studio 2022** called **Auto Versioning V3** that let you customize the version format and set it during the build. 
 The only problem is that if I launch `dotnet build solution.csproj` in the command prompt the extension does not set the version to the files (VS extensions work only inside the IDE (?)).

Every solution is really welcome, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use environment variables for that. In your csproj files, add these property groups:

```
    <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(APPVERSION)' == ''">
     <InformationalVersion>1.0.0.0</InformationalVersion>
    </PropertyGroup>

     <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(APPVERSION)' != ''">
      <InformationalVersion>$(APPVERSION)</InformationalVersion>
     </PropertyGroup>
```

If there is a environment variable "APPVERSION" set during the build, this will be used as InformationalVersion of the ouptut assembly, otherwise it will default to 1.0.0.0. You will just have to set APPVERSION in your makefile.

Comment: Is there a way to automate it? Like reading the actual date and increment the revision number?

Comment: For the date part, see this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1859113/append-date-and-time-to-an-environment-variable-in-linux-makefile As for the revision, I'd recommend using the git revision hash for that. You can get it with git rev-parse --short HEAD